# How to calculated a new column based on inputs in the same database

Tags: sql-server

I have a loan portfolio with several clients, each of which can be shown in the following table format.

```
DATE        DPD    DPD_BUCK    DATE_REST    RESTRUCTURED    REST_PERIOD
2017-03-01  90       90+       NULL             NO           NULL
2017-04-01  90       90+       NULL             NO           NULL
2017-05-01  2        0-29      2017-04-10       YES           1
2017-06-01  0         0        2017-04-10       YES           2
2017-07-01  0         0        2017-04-10       YES           3
2017-08-01  0         0        2017-04-10       YES           4
2017-09-01  0         0        2017-04-10       YES           5
2017-10-01  20       0-29      2017-04-10       YES           6
2017-11-01  51      30-59      2017-04-10       YES           7
2017-12-01  82      60-89      2017-04-10       YES           8
2018-01-01  90       90+       2017-04-10       YES           9
2018-02-01  90       90+       2017-04-10       YES          10
2018-03-01  90       90+       2017-04-10       YES          11
2018-04-01  90       90+       2017-04-10       YES          12
```

Column names

```
DPD = Number of overdue days on payments             
DPD_BUCK = Risk bucket  
DATE_REST = Date of restructuring of the loan   
REST_PERIOD = Number of months since last restructuring
```

I need to add a new column (DPD_UPD) which will adjust the original DPD values based on whether the loan was restructured or not using the following logic:

```
CASE
WHEN REST_PERIOD = 1 or REST_PERIOD = 2 THEN DPD (value 1 month before restructuring)
WHEN REST_PERIOD = 3 AND DPD = 0 THEN DPD (value from the previous period less 29 days)
WHEN REST_PERIOD = 3 AND DPD <> 0 THEN DPD (value from the previous period plus 29 days)
WHEN REST_PERIOD = 4 AND DPD = 0 THEN DPD (value from the previous period less 29 days)    
WHEN REST_PERIOD = 4 AND DPD <> 0 THEN (value from the previous period plus 29 days)
.
.
.
```

And so on until period 12, however, DPD cannot be less than 0 or more than 90.

The expected results should look like this:

```
DATE        DPD    DPD_UPD   DPD_BUCK      DATE_REST    RESTRUCTURED    REST_PERIOD
2017-03-01  90       90         90+            NULL             NO           NULL
2017-04-01  90       90         90+            NULL             NO           NULL
2017-05-01  2        90         0-29       2017-04-10          YES            1
2017-06-01  0        90          0         2017-04-10          YES            2
2017-07-01  0        61          0         2017-04-10          YES            3
2017-08-01  0        32          0         2017-04-10          YES            4
2017-09-01  0        3           0         2017-04-10          YES            5  
2017-10-01  20       32         0-29       2017-04-10          YES            6
2017-11-01  51       61        30-59       2017-04-10          YES            7
2017-12-01  82       90        60-89       2017-04-10          YES            8
2018-01-01  90       90         90+        2017-04-10          YES            9
2018-02-01  90       90         90+        2017-04-10          YES           10
2018-03-01  90       90         90+        2017-04-10          YES           11
2018-04-01  90       90         90+        2017-04-10          YES           12
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help.
Thx in advance

Comment: Isn't this `CASE` sample code answering your question `How to calculate`? What troubles are you facing?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL server 2014 management.

Comment: The issue I am facing is that I cannot figure out how to link the DPD value from the current period to the period before i.e if the loan is restructured and the DPD is 0 but it is the first or second month after restructuring I want the current DPD to be equal to the one before the restructuring occurred.

Comment: refer to lag() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql or lead() (the opposite)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the recursive CTE:

```
with
  r as (
    select top 1 DPD DPD_UPD, * from @lp order by [DATE]
      union all
    select
      case l.RESTRUCTURED
        when 'NO' then l.DPD
        else
          case
            when l.REST_PERIOD < 3 then
              coalesce((select DPD
                        from @lp i
                        where dateadd(mm,
                                datediff(mm, 0, l.DATE_REST) - 1,
                                0) = i.[DATE]), r.DPD_UPD)
            else
              iif(l.DPD = 0,
                  iif(r.DPD_UPD - 29 < 0, 0, r.DPD_UPD - 29),
                  iif(r.DPD_UPD + 29 > 90, 90, r.DPD_UPD + 29))
          end
      end,
      l.*
    from r join @lp l on dateadd(mm, 1, r.[DATE]) = l.[DATE]
  )
select * from r order by [DATE];
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/PKQR33915) it is possible to test my attempt.
But a solution with a cursor can be more preferable in terms of performance.